# How to query data according to date and time in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am working on a service layer implementation in asp mvc with LINQ. For example there are Users , Posts and Votes something like Stackoverflow. Each user have a reputation gained from upvotes and downvotes.

This vote table has following attributes: id , postTypeId, voteTypeId, creationDate , VoterId

This Post table has following attribute : id, userId ....

and User table includes : id

for each upvote 2 marks are given , for each downvote 1 mark is reduced

**I need how to write a query with Linq how to query , to show reputation change: 
reputation per Date , time and date, whether it's a upvote or downvote and related post**

these are the attributes I am going to use,

```
var jointable = from vote in _dataContext.Votes
    join post in _dataContext.Posts on vote.PostId equals post.Id
    where vote.VoterId== id
    select new
    {  
        vote.Id,
        vote.CreationDate,
        vote.PostId,
        vote.VoteTypeId,
        post.PostTypeId,
        post.Title,
        post.IsAnonymous 
    };
```

After this can somebody help me to query those attributes to return them as an object??

Comment: What is your _dataContext? Are you using Entity Framework, Linq to SQL or something else?

Comment: What are the VoteTypes? 1 = 'Up', 2 = 'Down'?

Comment: @ Wouter de Kort it's database..
here I am using Linq to SQL

Comment: @ Jodrell 
1= "Down" and 2= "up"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't that far off with what you have already, you just need the date range condition i.e.

```
var startDate = ...; // assume this will be selected from the UI
// assuming we are working with UTC (if you aren't, you should be)
startDate = startDate.ToUniversalTime();
var endDate = startDate.AddHours(24); // include full 24 hour day
var jointable = from vote in _dataContext.Votes
    join post in _dataContext.Posts on vote.PostId equals post.Id
    where vote.VoterId == id && vote.CreationDate >= startDate && vote.CreationDate < endDate
    select new
    {  
        vote.Id,
        vote.CreationDate,
        vote.PostId,
        vote.VoteTypeId,
        post.PostTypeId,
        post.Title,
        post.IsAnonymous 
    };
```